# Is there an easy way to create thumbnails of various document formats like Word, Excel on iOS?

Tags: ios

Is there a built-in mechanism in the iOS SDK that I could use to render **thumbnails** (UIImage) of arbitrary document types, like **Word, Excel, PDF, image formats**, etc - whatever iOS is capable of previewing?
It only ever needs to create a thumbnail of the first page.

I have code to scale down PDFs and images but I thought, as iOS can preview Word and others, maybe there is something built in?

Comment: I think you're looking for the QuickLook framework: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010413-SW1. I'm not really familiar with its use though.

Comment: That's not quite what I want. QuickLook framework loads the entire file and previews it. I only need the first page. I could maybe preview it and then render in context of an image but that's just an overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the trick to open office document file (docx, xls, pptx), display all pages in thumbnail bar, let the user to open any page in the same view while taping on any thumbnail.

Here are the steps

- Open file in UIWebView
- Take screenshot of every page and add in scroll-able thumbnail view bar(recursive)
- Add a custom button over each thumbnail image to enable user interaction

Import QuartzCore.framework

Confugure.h file like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    BOOL finished;
    float currentOffset;
    float pointToAddNextThumbnail;
    NSURLRequest *request;
    int totalFileHeight;
    int currentExecutingSnapshot;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIWebView* webView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIScrollView* thumbnailScrollView;
@end
```

.m file like

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end
#define pageHeight 360
#define pageWidth 320
#define thumbnailHeight 88
#define thumbnailWidht 70
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView,thumbnailScrollView;
#pragma mark
#pragma mark VC Delegates
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Reader" ofType:@"doc"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight)];

    [self.webView  setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.webView  loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView ];

    self.thumbnailScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, pageHeight+5, pageWidth, thumbnailHeight)];
    [self.thumbnailScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.thumbnailScrollView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark webView Delegate Methods
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   //  NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
    CGSize z =  self.webView.scrollView.contentSize;
    totalFileHeight= z.height;
    NSLog(@"totalFileHeight in pxls %d",totalFileHeight);
    totalFileHeight=totalFileHeight/pageHeight;
    NSLog(@"totalFileHeight in pages %d",totalFileHeight);
    [self takeScreenShotAndReloadWebViewWithPage];
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark utitlityMehtods
-(void)takeScreenShotAndReloadWebViewWithPage
{
    float widthOfThumbnailForScrollView = (thumbnailWidht+5);
    float widhtOfScrollViewContant = (currentExecutingSnapshot*widthOfThumbnailForScrollView)+widthOfThumbnailForScrollView;
    self.thumbnailScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widhtOfScrollViewContant,50);
    self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, currentOffset);
   // [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0,%f)",currentOffset]];

    //take Snapshot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, pageHeight));
    [self.webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //set frames of thumbailButton and thumnailImage
    CGRect thumbnailFrame = CGRectMake(pointToAddNextThumbnail, 0, thumbnailWidht, thumbnailHeight);
    UIButton *thumbnailButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:thumbnailFrame];
    UIImageView *thumbnailImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:thumbnailFrame];
    [thumbnailImage setImage:img];
    thumbnailButton.tag = currentOffset;
    [thumbnailButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [thumbnailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(thumnailButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.thumbnailScrollView addSubview:thumbnailImage];
    [self.thumbnailScrollView addSubview:thumbnailButton];
    [thumbnailImage release];
    [thumbnailButton release];

    pointToAddNextThumbnail = pointToAddNextThumbnail+thumbnailWidht+5;
    currentOffset = currentOffset + pageHeight;

    if (currentExecutingSnapshot < totalFileHeight)
    {
        NSLog(@"currentExecutingSnapshot %d",currentExecutingSnapshot);
        currentExecutingSnapshot ++;
        //[self.webView  loadRequest:request];
        //make a recursive call and take snapshot of all pages
        [self takeScreenShotAndReloadWebViewWithPage];
    }
    else
    {
        [self finishedFethingThumbnails];
    }
}
-(void)finishedFethingThumbnails
{
     self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark IBaction
-(IBAction)thumnailButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [[self.webView scrollView] setZoomScale:0 animated:YES];
    [[self.webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, sender.tag) animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark dealloc
-(void)dealloc
{
    [webView release];
    [thumbnailScrollView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Download sample project from http://abdus.me/downloads/testThumbnail.zip